# How to disable touchpad during programming in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, touch

In my laptop (Dell Inspiron), when I code, the palm touch in the touch pad moves the cursor, or screen or to different application. I am finding it annoying to program.
There is an option to disable touch pad in the system, but it works for a very short time.
I am looking for any hot key in Ubuntu, which will enable/disable touch pad so that my coding is not affected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Refer](https://askubuntu.com/q/743252)

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution would be to install a [Touchpad Indicator](https://launchpad.net/touchpad-indicator).

Or if you prefer command line , you can use [xinput](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xinput) command which lets you configure and test X input devices.

For example:

```
xinput list
```

Returns this device list on my computer :

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt Microsoft USB Optical Mouse        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Wired Keyboard 400              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

disable device :

```
xinput -disable DEVICE_ID
```

enable device :

```
xinput -enable DEVICE_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

To disable the touchpad, use following cmd to disable the  'psmouse' module.

```
$ sudo modprobe -r psmouse
```

To enable it back, use

```
$ sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Answer (score 0):

OK the best way by far to do it is in this post  https://askubuntu.com/questions/773595/how-can-i-disable-touchpad-while-typing-on-ubuntu-16-04-syndaemon-isnt-working
In this post look… for the python script answer from "quacker"
While implementing this python script use the
`xinput` command to modify his script

1. Run the xinput command to display all input devices.
2. Run   `xinput test <device id>` to pinpoint your keyboard.   Lookup
   xinput test on google to understand how this works.
3. Change the device id    used in the script provided by "quacker".
4. Run the script later on to see how the "Enable touchpad" "Disable
   touchpad" are printed out in the script.
5. You can then run this as background process using nohup (Google nohup)
6. you can also add this to your startup applications in ubuntu. Search for "startup" after pressing Super key.
7. After rebooting check to see this running as a process using the command `ps ax | grep yourscriptname.py`

At the end the result is rewarding. If you did not enjoy the process of fixing a touchpad irritation on a linux installation you should not use linux. Linux is all about such customizations.